# HealthKit WorkoutSession failure when workout spans 2 calendar days

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, healthkit, watchos

My Apple Watch app calls `.start` on a `HealthStore` object that begins a `WorkoutSession`.  I find that if users begin a workout e.g. at 11:30pm on day 1 and end the workout at 12:30am on day 2, they are unable to `.end` the workout and the delegate method `func workoutSession(_ workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession, didFailWithError error: Error)` is called with an error message that the workout is not current.

Am I doing anything wrong or is this a bug? (I filed a [radar](https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=36336342) ) Possible work arounds?

```
  func start(_ workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession) {
        healthStore.start(workoutSession)
    }

    func end(_ workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession) {
        healthStore.end(workoutSession)
    }



 func workoutSession(_ workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        showAlertWith(title: "WorkoutSession Failure", message: "tell Gary this: \(error) he'll fix it")
    }
```